# Time difference calculation in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery with 3 columns. I need to calculate the 4th column (Time_since_activity_min) as below

```
Name    Activity    Time            Time_since_activity_min
John    2           11:01:00    0
John    0           11:02:00    1
John    0           11:03:00    2
John    0           11:04:00    3
John    4           11:05:00    0
John    0           11:06:00    1
John    0           11:07:00    2
John    5           11:07:00    0
```

If activity column value is more than 0 (Activity > 0) then 4th column value will be 0 means activity done at that time. If Activity column value is 0 (Activity = 0) then 4th column value will be (Time - Time of the previous row when Activity was > 0).

Please suggest how it can be achieved in bigquery as SQL code. Thanks

LAG function in bigquery

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of `gaps and islnads` problem, so you might consider below as well.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'John' Name, Activity, TIME_ADD(TIME '11:01:00', INTERVAL diff MINUTE) time
    FROM UNNEST([2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5]) Activity WITH offset
    JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 7)) diff WITH offset USING (offset)
)
-- query starts here
SELECT *,
       -- calculate an elapsed time since min time over each *island*
       TIME_DIFF(time, MIN(time) OVER w1, MINUTE) AS Time_since_activity_min   
  FROM (
    -- find *islands* based on given *gaps*(Activity in this case) 
    SELECT *, COUNTIF(Activity > 0) OVER w0 AS Grp
      FROM sample_table
    WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY time)
  ) WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY Name, Grp);

--query results
+------+----------+----------+-----+-------------------------+
| Name | Activity |   time   | Grp | Time_since_activity_min |
+------+----------+----------+-----+-------------------------+
| John |        2 | 11:01:00 |   1 |                       0 |
| John |        0 | 11:02:00 |   1 |                       1 |
| John |        0 | 11:03:00 |   1 |                       2 |
| John |        0 | 11:04:00 |   1 |                       3 |
| John |        4 | 11:05:00 |   2 |                       0 |
| John |        0 | 11:06:00 |   2 |                       1 |
| John |        0 | 11:07:00 |   2 |                       2 |
| John |        5 | 11:08:00 |   3 |                       0 |
+------+----------+----------+-----+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi @Jaytiger, the above query works perfectly when there is a single user and time is only for single day as I have mentioned in the question. In my environment, I have multiple users and per minute records for different dates (there is a 'date' column) so when I am using above query in my table creation and then filtering down record based on 'Name=John' and 'date=2023-04-01' for example I am not getting desired result. Please see below output in next comment

Comment: Name Activity date                 time               Time_since_activity_min
John 0         2023-04-01 00:00:00        0
John 0         2023-04-01 00:01:00        1
John 0         2023-04-01 00:02:00        0
John 0         2023-04-01 00:03:00        1 
John 0         2023-04-01 00:04:00        2
John 0         2023-04-01 00:05:00        3
John 0         2023-04-01 00:06:00        4
John 0         2023-04-01 00:07:00        5
John 0         2023-04-01 00:08:00        6
John 0         2023-04-01 00:09:00        7
John 0         2023-04-01 00:10:00        0

Comment: @Awssylearn, `Activity` in your output is all `0`s which means there is no `gaps` in your input table and `Time_since_activity_min` should be `0` to `10` sequencially.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one CTE to calculate the differences in minutes and to group the rows in аctivity group:

[image]

Then, we just need to sum the minutes in each group:

[image]

Here is the full working example:

```
WITH my_table AS (
  SELECT 'John' AS Name, 2 AS Activity, CAST('11:01:00' AS TIME) AS Time UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John', 0,  CAST('11:02:00' AS TIME) UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John', 0,  CAST('11:03:00' AS TIME) UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John', 0,  CAST('11:04:00' AS TIME) UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John', 4,  CAST('11:05:00' AS TIME) UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John', 0,  CAST('11:06:00' AS TIME) UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John', 0,  CAST('11:07:00' AS TIME) UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John', 5,  CAST('11:07:00' AS TIME)
), DataSource AS 
(
  SELECT *
        ,IF(Activity > 0, 0, TIME_DIFF(Time, LAG(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Time,Activity), MINUTE)) AS Time_since_activity_min
        ,SUM(IF(Activity > 0, 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Time,Activity) as group_id
  FROM my_table
  ORDER BY Name, Time
)
SELECT Name, Time, Activity
      ,SUM(Time_since_activity_min) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY Time,Activity) AS Time_since_activity_min
FROM DataSource
ORDER BY Name, Time, Activity
```

Note, that I am ordering the rows by name, time and activity, as your last two rows have duplicate times. I guess in your real data the times will be different and the activity can be leave aside the ordering.